# Django include several times

Tags: django, include

mi question is, can i repeat several times an {include} tag ?

I think use FOR or something like this, but i don't have idea how to do it

```
{% include tag%}
```

any idea please? i'm new in django.

Comment: Is there something in particular you are trying to do with `{% include %}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

urls.py

```
url(u'your_url/$', YourView.as_view(), name='your_view'),
```

views.py

```
class YourView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tags = [
             'template_one.html',
             'template_two.html',
        ]

        return {
            'tags': tags,
        }
```

template.html

```
{% for tag in tags %}
     {% include tag %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hopefully tag is the path to some template file.

Comment: who is tags? 
as I can define how many times it is repeated? tell me please

Comment: Most likely tags would be a list of strings that you would want to include.  You can pass it to your template through the context passed from your function in views.py

Comment: I've changed my answer to provide a little more context.